# Kong-OIDC plugin logout

Tags: keycloak, openid-connect, logout, kong, konga

I'm working with `kong-oidc` plugin using `keycloack` (https://github.com/nokia/kong-oidc) as authentication provider.

The configuration works as expected, (i use `konga` as interface). The login procedure is fine.

Now i need to logout but i don't understand how to reach the `logout` endpoint.

How can i logout from the application ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some test, i found a solution and it was simplier than expected.

With my oidc configuration, i just needed to add a route `logout` to to the service that uses the plugin.

> This issue discussion clarify some aspects
> https://github.com/nokia/kong-oidc/issues/30#issuecomment-487464297

[image]

Comment: What Kong version did you use? I'm using 2.0.3. I install kong-oidc globally and have service named "order" with 2 routes:
- "/order" with "Strip Path" is true
- "/logout" with "Strip Path" is false
when I call "https://example.com/logout" and get "message: 'no Route matched with those values'"
Wondering what did I miss

Comment: I use kong:2.3.2-alpine (from my dockerfile)

Comment: Could you please share your Dockerffile or configurations of your Service/Routes? Does our upstream service need to have /logout route as well?
Thank you very much!

Comment: i just have the dockerfile https://jpst.it/2VLox. The precondition is that you use the kong-oidc plugin. The interface you see is from Konga https://github.com/pantsel/konga. To use logout you should define the logout route (as in the picture) for the service that use the kong-oidc plugin

Comment: kong-oidc has that you install from lua is not the latest version. The latest version resolve a bug. If you see my dockerfile i build kong-oidc from source, to do that just clone kong-oidc from github https://github.com/nokia/kong-oidc and build the dockerfile

Comment: I still can't get it work, here are my configurations, please help me review it
https://jpst.it/2VObZ